# Will Disabling GPU also stop heat generation from GPU

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, gpu, cooling

My laptop is lenovo z560 with nvidia 310m graphics card, everything is fine: there is no dust + new thermal grease but the laptop is old. I think only gpu is producing heat when any graphics on laptop screen run and i don't know why.

So i want to disable the gpu in device manager because there is not much graphical use, will it useful in heat?

**Edit:** Because my laptop have only 1 integrated nvidia gpu so installed tools like: MSI After Burner and EVGA PrecisionX for limiting/lowering the gpu power and worked well on my nvidia. I am currently using **MSI After Burner**.

Comment: Unless you also have Intel graphics, disabling the GPU will cause you to lose your graphical environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A GPU is needed to produce the video signal that is sent to your monitor. Without one, you don't have a GUI. Some computers come with two graphics cards: integrated and discrete. Newer CPUs now have low-power GPUs built in; these GPUs are are the integrated ones, since they are a part of a greater processing unit. A Discrete GPU is its own unit and can be much more powerful, while producing more heat.

Disabling your discrete graphics will definitely cool down your laptop, but it's only advisable if you happen to have integrated graphics as well. Unless you have both, disabling your graphics card will cause you to lose your desktop, with no easy way to get it back.

If you do have switchable graphics (integrated and discrete), go ahead and disable the NVIDIA card. You'll lose performance, but your laptop will run cooler and you'll get better battery life. Check to see if you have an additional graphics card in Device Manager.

Comment: I know about this laptop, I have single integrated nvidia card which I disabled but display is working also after restarts.

Comment: @BlackFire I should've added this to the answer, but disabling the card in DevMan merely disables the driver, not the card. That is why you have the basic driver now and can't change your resolution.

Comment: does it generate heat or not? because it looks cpu is working as a replacement of gpu for graphics

Comment: @BlackFire you're still using the thing because you're currently using the graphical interface. So yes, it will still get warm, and i think it might get warmer with the generic driver than it will with the NVIDIA one.

Comment: so should i install the drivers again?

Comment: and try to limit gpu's processing power

Comment: That would be a better way, yes.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a BIOS option to disable the external GPU and keep the internal one, then it could well reduce the heat generation.

Using device manager though is unlikely to make much difference.

Answer (score 0):

In short. Yes, a GPU thats not being powered on shouldn't produce heat. However, make sure your laptop has integrated graphics before disabling anything.

Answer (score 0):

to redcuce heat, use a lower performance power plan. using a gpu actually reduces heat since it decreases the workload of the cpu.